# Tmux: What is the default format for `tmux ls` and how to check it?

Tags: tmux

An example output with the default format of "tmux ls" is like this below (for me):

```
$ tmux ls 
26: 1 windows (created Fri Apr 23 10:57:23 2021) [90x30]
27: 1 windows (created Sat Apr 24 01:40:51 2021) [90x30]
28: 1 windows (created Sat Apr 24 01:41:09 2021) [90x30]
```

Here I want to see the list sorted by the date, but I couldn't find a snippet for that on the internet so I'm trying to learn the format and script by myself. Now for the beginning, I want to know the current format, config used for "tmux ls", and how to check it. I googled SO and checked the [document](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS), but couldn't find neither of that how to check or the default format, so I'd like to know is there a way to know them?

added:

So the question here is simply, again, what format (the xxxxx part of `tmux ls -F "xxxxx"`) is being used as the default for `tmux ls`. This IS the question. (I believe this is quite simple and understandable question...)

Comment: I think `tmux` assigns session IDs sequentially. I don't know what the maximal possible ID is; IDK if `tmux` wraps and reuses old IDs; IDK how extensively you use `tmux`. If you think you're far from a situation where session IDs are reused then simple `tmux ls | sort -n` may be enough to show you earlier sessions first. Explicitly sorting by date may not be needed.

Comment: I'm not talking about maximum ID. The result is just an example for "tmux ls" output with default format. Actually my "tmux ls" result shows me a tens or hundreds of tmux sessions by the order of 0-9 and a-z. So now, I want to sort the list by the date. I can use awk, sort, and such once I manage to format the result by placing a space between them, so as the post, I'd like to know how to check the default (or script to format and sort by the date if you know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code bears the answer in [cmd-list-sessions.c](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/6a8d848a3e123ec5a0bb9747522a343c843f1c61/cmd-list-sessions.c#L31) [(as raw text)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/6c2bf0e22119804022c8038563b9865999f5a026/cmd-list-sessions.c), the default format is

```
"#{session_name}: #{session_windows} windows (created #{t:session_created})\
#{?session_grouped, (group ,}#{session_group}#{?session_grouped,),}\
#{?session_attached, (attached),}"
```

Since you want to sort it, I recommend using a format with `#{session_created}` so that timestamps are standard Unix time (which is easier to sort).

Comment: Very nice. Thanks. I made what I wanted to do, sorting by the date (newest order), with: `tmux ls -F "#{session_created} #{session_name}: #{session_windows} windows (created #{t:session_created})#{?session_grouped, (group ,}#{session_group}#{?session_grouped,),}#{?session_attached, (attached),}" | sort -Vr | sed 's/\S*\s//'`